# Loop through JSON response and return values that matches another JSON response into a new key value

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following API call returned values that has an id value

```
var sites = 
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1433,
      "name": "Bronx 1",
      "address": "5288 McGlynn Hills",
      "latitude": 51.05,
      "longitude": -114.066,
      "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
      "units": "imperial",
      "postal_code": null,
      "city": null,
      "state_province_region": null,
      "country": null,
      "rentable_area_from_lease": null,
      "rentable_area_from_floors": 0,
      "additional_site_common_area": 200,
      "total_site_common_area": 200,
      "site_attributes_url": "/api/1/sites/1433/attributes"
    },
    {
      "id": 1434,
      "name": "Bronx 2",
      "address": "126 Mann Divide",
      "latitude": 51.05,
      "longitude": -114.066,
      "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
      "units": "imperial",
      "postal_code": null,
      "city": null,
      "state_province_region": null,
      "country": null,
      "rentable_area_from_lease": null,
      "rentable_area_from_floors": 0,
      "additional_site_common_area": 200,
      "total_site_common_area": 200,
      "site_attributes_url": "/api/1/sites/1434/attributes"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to use the ID value from the call above an compare it to the following API response site_id value

```
var floors = 
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 118,
      "label": "Crowded floor",
      "managed": true,
      "unusable_area": 0,
      "rentable_area": 100,
      "site_common_area": 50,
      "floor_common_area": 50,
      "assigned_area": 0,
      "image_url": "/GetFloorImage?z=118",
      "site_id": 1433,
      "icon_scale_factor": 0.2,
      "floor_plan_images": [
        {
          "pixel_width": 2048,
          "format": "png",
          "coordinate_scale_factor": 2,
          "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/118/plan_image/2048.png"
        },
        {
          "pixel_width": 4096,
          "format": "png",
          "coordinate_scale_factor": 4,
          "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/118/plan_image/4096.png"
        }
      ],
      "directories": [
        "/api/1/directories/1390"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 119,
      "label": "Normal floor",
      "managed": true,
      "unusable_area": 0,
      "rentable_area": 200,
      "site_common_area": 0,
      "floor_common_area": 200,
      "assigned_area": 0,
      "image_url": "/GetFloorImage?z=119",
      "site_id": 1453,
      "icon_scale_factor": 0.7,
      "floor_plan_images": [
        {
          "pixel_width": 2048,
          "format": "png",
          "coordinate_scale_factor": 2,
          "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/119/plan_image/2048.png"
        },
        {
          "pixel_width": 4096,
          "format": "png",
          "coordinate_scale_factor": 4,
          "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/119/plan_image/4096.png"
        }
      ],
      "directories": [
        "/api/1/directories/1391"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

When site.id = floors.site_id I want to build a new key value pair that looks like this: only for the matched values

```
var match {floor.id: site.name}
```

I am having trouble looping over both and returning values any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Abdullah Albyati,

I try to created what u asked but, it's actually not that usefull but here it is:

```js
var floors =
{
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 118,
            "label": "Crowded floor",
            "managed": true,
            "unusable_area": 0,
            "rentable_area": 100,
            "site_common_area": 50,
            "floor_common_area": 50,
            "assigned_area": 0,
            "image_url": "/GetFloorImage?z=118",
            "site_id": 1452,
            "icon_scale_factor": 0.2,
            "floor_plan_images": [
                {
                    "pixel_width": 2048,
                    "format": "png",
                    "coordinate_scale_factor": 2,
                    "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/118/plan_image/2048.png"
                },
                {
                    "pixel_width": 4096,
                    "format": "png",
                    "coordinate_scale_factor": 4,
                    "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/118/plan_image/4096.png"
                }
            ],
            "directories": [
                "/api/1/directories/1390"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 119,
            "label": "Normal floor",
            "managed": true,
            "unusable_area": 0,
            "rentable_area": 200,
            "site_common_area": 0,
            "floor_common_area": 200,
            "assigned_area": 0,
            "image_url": "/GetFloorImage?z=119",
            "site_id": 1453,
            "icon_scale_factor": 0.7,
            "floor_plan_images": [
                {
                    "pixel_width": 2048,
                    "format": "png",
                    "coordinate_scale_factor": 2,
                    "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/119/plan_image/2048.png"
                },
                {
                    "pixel_width": 4096,
                    "format": "png",
                    "coordinate_scale_factor": 4,
                    "url": "http://my-machine/api/1/floors/119/plan_image/4096.png"
                }
            ],
            "directories": [
                "/api/1/directories/1391"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 2
};

var sites =
{
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1433,
            "name": "Bronx 1",
            "address": "5288 McGlynn Hills",
            "latitude": 51.05,
            "longitude": -114.066,
            "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
            "units": "imperial",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "state_province_region": null,
            "country": null,
            "rentable_area_from_lease": null,
            "rentable_area_from_floors": 0,
            "additional_site_common_area": 200,
            "total_site_common_area": 200,
            "site_attributes_url": "/api/1/sites/1433/attributes"
        },
        {
            // "id": 1434,
            "id": 1453,
            "name": "Bronx 2",
            "address": "126 Mann Divide",
            "latitude": 51.05,
            "longitude": -114.066,
            "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
            "units": "imperial",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "state_province_region": null,
            "country": null,
            "rentable_area_from_lease": null,
            "rentable_area_from_floors": 0,
            "additional_site_common_area": 200,
            "total_site_common_area": 200,
            "site_attributes_url": "/api/1/sites/1434/attributes"
        }
    ]
}


var conbined = floors.response.reduce((obj, floor) => {
    var site_id = floor.site_id;
    var site = sites.response.find(site => site.id === site_id);
    if(site) {
        console.log(site.name);
        return { ...obj, floor_site_id: site.name }

    }
    return obj;
}, {});


console.log(conbined);
```

In the data you gave there was no data to combine so i changed one of the id's. Hope this works for you

Comment: thanks for fixing the data to combine, I fixed it in the original post. Your solution almost there I guess. This part is logging matched site names to the console but the final output is only doing this {site_id=Bronx 2} so it is matching just 1 value and not returning the ID

Comment: Well this `var match {floor.id: site.name}` object is not a valid object and i assume what i've returned would be usefull but what do you need actually just write it down and i can change it